# The JSON Document must be valid

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk

I am trying to do a simple update on a table in dynamo using the AWS PHP SDK. `I get the error The JSON Document must be valid and be an object at its root.`
on this code below. This looks like a valid JSON to me. The error is showing on the line of the `$eav` variable.

```
                $eav = $marshaler->marshalJson('
                      {":Aname": {"S": ' . $profile['Aname'] . '}}
                 ');

                // dynamodb table update (NEW ATTRIBUTE)
                $params = [
                        'TableName' => 'table-example',
                        'Key' => 'table-key-example',
                        'UpdateExpression' => 
                            'set Aname = :Aname',
                        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav,
                        'ReturnValues' => 'UPDATED_NEW'
                ];

                try {
                        $result = $dynamodb->updateItem($params);
                        echo "Updated item.\n";
                        print_r($result['Attributes']);
                    
                    } catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
                        echo "Unable to update item:\n";
                        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                    }
```

Comment: Why are you manually making JSON? What does `$profile['Aname']` contain?

Comment: The value of the `ExpressionAttributeValues` parameter should not be a string, but an associative array. The SDK will marshal it for you. So instead of having your `$eav` variable be a string, just use `[":Aname" => ["S" => $profile['Aname']]]`.

Comment: I'm following the docs and that's how it showed to create the variable. ```$profile['Aname']``` is a string value

Comment: Which docs are you referring to? I am looking at [these ones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#updateitem).

Comment: I'm looking at these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.03.html)

Comment: that solution did not work @CRice. I get the same error

Comment: @CRice. That solution did actually work. I am getting a 400 response now saying ```Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes```

Comment: This would indicate that `$profile['Aname']` is empty. Perhaps whichever profile you are using does not have an `'Aname'` set for it.

Comment: I replaced ```$profile['Aname']``` with ```"test"``` and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$eav = $marshaler->marshalJson('{":Aname": "' . $profile['Aname'] . '"}');

// dynamodb table update (NEW ATTRIBUTE)
$params = [
    'TableName' => 'table-example',
    'Key' => 'table-key-example',
    'UpdateExpression' => 'set Aname = :Aname',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav,
    'ReturnValues' => 'UPDATED_NEW'
];

try {
    $result = $dynamodb->updateItem($params);
    echo "Updated item.\n";
    print_r($result['Attributes']);

} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to update item:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```